# Why don't WebView script injections work?

Tags: react-native, webview

this document suggests that I should be able to inject values into a web page displayed by the WebView component such that the value can be used by loaded the page:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#communicating-between-js-and-native

specifically, the code below shows how to set a value within the `window` object but does not show how it is used:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const runFirst = `
      window.isNativeApp = true;
      true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
    `;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <WebView
          source={{uri: 'my-url-here'}}
          injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={runFirst}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

the page I'm loading looks like this:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
    alert(window.isNativeApp)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

which displays `undefined`.  I've also tried:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
    var fn = function() {
      alert(window.isNativeApp)
    }
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

with identical results.  given that I'm supposed to be able to send the webpage values, how am I supposed to use them?

from my `package.json`:

```
"react-dom": "~16.9.0",
"react-native": "^0.62.1",
"react-native-webview": "^8.2.1",
```

**Appendix I**

in fact, the above doesn't seem to run at all.  if I try the following:

```js
    const runFirst = `
      console.log('INJECTION')
      alert('INJECTION')
      true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
    `;
```

I get neither an alert, nor a trace in the log.  of course, I'm not sure whether `alert()` can work before the document is loaded, or whether the log would be visible to me in the regular app's console output

by contrast `injectedJavaScript` does seem to run, albeit *after* the document loads, which means that at the time that the `<script>` in my doc runs, the value hasn't yet been set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the next poor sod that struggles with this, the library is broken and will (someday) be fixed, but in the meantime, this works:

```js
<WebView
  source={{uri: 'my-url-here'}}
  injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={runFirst}
  onMessage={event => { alert(event.nativeEvent.data )}}
/>
```

the `onMessage` is intended for communications in the other direction but its mere presence makes the code work